# Get Specific Value from entity.OriginalValues in EFv4

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-4, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have an `ObjectStateEntry` "entry". I need to get a property value from this "entry" like so, but I don't know how to specify the property I want. I use `entry.OriginalValues(propName)` but then what?

Comment: FYI, you can use an ordinand (a integer indicating position within a list) to choose the item you want to query like so:
entry.CurrentValues.GetValue(1). You have to figure out where the property you want is in the list - one easy way to accomplish this is by using the above code and seeing what it comes back with - then measuring from there.
I am hoping there is an even easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand you can try something like this:

```
entry.CurrentValues.Item[propName];
```

or

```
entry.CurrentValues.GetValue(entry.CurrentValues.GetOrdinal(propName))
```